# Como pegar o value de botões criados através de um loop foreach em php/laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, button, value

Pessoal eu tenho um array com tamanhos de um produto, segue o exemplo do array:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E para cada tamanho eu crio um botão através de um foreach, segue trecho do código onde crio os botões:

```
<div class="item item-stock">
    <label for="stock">Tamanho: </label>
    @foreach($stocks as $stock)
        <button id="stock" class="btn-stock" value="{{ $stock->id }}" data-quantity="{{ $stock->quantity }}" onclick="verifyStock();">{{ $stock->unit->name }}</button>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

Para mim prosseguir com minha aplicação eu preciso verificar se o produto tem estoque e para verificar isso eu preciso da quantidade, uma informação que já vem no array, e eu estou tentando jogar ela em um script através de um data attributes, porém o problema é que não importa em qual botão eu clico ele sempre vem o valor do primeiro elemento do array... e como lá em cima eu já fiz um foreach era para estar vindo certo, não era? Segue abaixo a minha função js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    verifyStock();
});

function verifyStock() {
    var quantity = $('#stock').val();
    // var quantity = $('#stock').attr('data-quantity');
    console.log(quantity);
}
```

Alguém poderia me explicar o que está faltando, onde está faltando e o pq?

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que o erro está ocorrendo porque você está tentando pegar o valor a partir de um ID, o problema é que no HTML o ID é único, e quando você faz o foreach, você está iterando mais elementos com o ID "stock". Uma solução simples seria enviar o próprio elemento com o 'this', e buscar os valores que você precisa pela response dele.

```
    <button class="btn-stock" value="{{ $stock->id }}" data-quantity="{{ $stock->quantity }}" onclick="verifyStock(this);">{{ $stock->unit->name }}</button>
```

e no script:

```
function verifyStock(response) {
    console.log(response);
}
```

A partir daí você pode manipular o response, que será o botão clicado, e retornar os valores dos 'data', do 'value' e tudo que estiver dentro deste botão

Answer (score 0):

O problema ta no teu codigo js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    verifyStock();
});

function verifyStock() {
    var quantity = $('#stock').val();
    // var quantity = $('#stock').attr('data-quantity');
    console.log(quantity);
}
```

perceba que voce esta buscando o valor do id stock, para o js existem varios ids stack pois vc rodou no foreach dai ele vai pegar o valor do primeiro elemento com esse id

A solução seria colocar o id junto e enviar para a função js assim

```
<div class="item item-stock">
    <label for="stock">Tamanho: </label>
    @foreach($stocks as $stock)
        <button id="stock{{$stock->id}}" class="btn-stock" value="{{ $stock->id }}" data-quantity="{{ $stock->quantity }}" onclick="verifyStock({{ $stock->id }});">{{ $stock->unit->name }}</button>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        verifyStock();
    });

    function verifyStock(id) {
        var quantity = $('#stock'+id).val();
        // var quantity = $('#stock').attr('data-quantity');
        console.log(quantity);
    }
```